# Is it better for siblings to meet at a young age?

Tags: siblings

My children are 3 and 18 months, their siblings from another father are 6, 7 and 8. They have never met each other.

Is it better for them to meet now or to wait until they are teenagers or adults? My wife's ex is against any kind of contact between them.

Comment: It's pretty natural for silbings to meet when they are young. If you want them to feel like a Family then I would say now. If not then I would say never. To wait for years unter they are Teenagers does not have any benefit. If they have no Memoires to share they possibly won't care much about each other.

Comment: This sounds like more of a legal question than a parenting one. Whether it's better to meet now or later, how will that information be of any use without the cooperation of the children's other parent?

Comment: The should meet while they are innocent children.  They will not meld well the older they get and feel more like distant family.  Like a cousin's cousin kind of family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a complicated situation. I'm sorry that one of the parents doesn't want the other children to interact, very sad. However, even if you want them to meet, how much control do you have over it and how much drama will it cause everyone if it is forced?

The greatest lesson I've learned in the world of nuclear families and separation is this: If you can't control it, let it go.  Some day they'll all be older and make their own choices and voices heard. Until then, don't let an issue you can't control cause friction in your own home. You can control that :)

Best of luck!